# Display UserDetails on popup Modal doesn't show up ASP.NET CORE MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, datatable, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to create `popup modal` with User Details when click on `<tr>`. I create function on controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetUserDetails(int? Id)
        {
            TicketVM ticketVM = new()
            {
                ApplicationUser = _unitOfwork.ApplicationUser.Get(Id.GetValueOrDefault())
            };

            if (Id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if(ticketVM.ApplicationUser == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(ticketVM);
        }
```

And In my `Index.cshtml`

```
@model IEnumerable<VmSTicketing.Models.Ticket>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/AdminLTE/_Layout.cshtml";

}


<br />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <h2 class="text-primary">Lista tiketa</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 text-right">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-action="Upsert"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> &nbsp; Novi tiket</a>
    </div>
</div>

<br />

<div class="p-4 border rounded">
    <table id="tblData" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr class="table-info">
                <th>Opis</th>
                <th>Datum i vrijeme slanja</th>
                <th>Vrsta Tiketa</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Datum i vrijeme zavrsetka</th>
                <th>Korisnik</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>

<partial name="UserDetails" />


@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/js/ticket.js"></script>
}
```

And in `ticket.js` I add something like

```
function loadDataTable() {
    dataTable = $('#tblData').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Manager/Ticket/GetAll"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "description", "width": "10%" },
            { "data": "dateAndTime", "width": "15%" },
            { "data": "ticketType.name", "width": "10%" },
            { "data": "status", "width": "10%" },
            { "data": "answered", "width": "15%" },
            { "data": "applicationUser.name", "width": "10%" },
            {
                "data": "id",
                "render": function (data) {
                    return `
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <a href="/Manager/Discussion/OpenDiscussion/${data}" class="btn btn-primary text-white" style="cursor:pointer">
                                    <i class="fas fa-comments"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a href="/Manager/Ticket/Details/${data}" class="btn btn-success text-white" style="cursor:pointer">
                                    <i class="fas fa-info"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a onclick=Delete("/Manager/Ticket/Delete/${data}") class="btn btn-danger text-white" style="cursor:pointer">
                                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> 
                                </a>                              
                            </div>
                           `;
                }, "width": "15%"
            }
        ]
    });
}
```

And here is my function to popup window

```
$(".detalji").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("userDetails");
    $.get("/Manager/Ticket/UserDetails?id=" + id, function (result, status) {
        $("#container").append(result);
        $("#userDetails").modal({ show: true })
    })
})
```

But when I click in `<tr>` nothing show up and In console log I get error

```
jquery.min.js:2 GET https://localhost:44315/Manager/Ticket/GetUserDetails?id=undefined 500
```

I try to understand what is wrong and try to debug but I assume the problem is in my function where modal is popup
Anyone how can tell me where I made mistak and what I made wrong ?

Here is Demo

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dipakthoke07/t53cyutt/42/)

**UPDATE**

UserDetails.cshtml

```
   @model VmSTicketing.Models.ViewModels.TicketVM

<div class="modal fade" id="userDetails">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Podaci o Useru</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row dataTable">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label">Ime i Prezime</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Ticket.ApplicationUser.Name" disabled id="ImePrezime" name="ImePrezime">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br>

                <div class="row dataTable">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label">Email Adresa</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Ticket.ApplicationUser.Email" disabled id="Email" name="Email">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br>

                <div class="row dataTable">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label">Broj Telefona</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" asp-for="Ticket.ApplicationUser.PhoneNumber" class="form-control" disabled id="BrTel" name="BrTel">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />

                <div class="row dataTable">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label">Klijent</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" asp-for="Ticket.ApplicationUser.Client" class="form-control" disabled id="klijent" name="klijent">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `id` is undefined: `https://localhost:44315/Manager/Ticket/GetUserDetails?id=undefined`. What is `$(this).attr("userDetailsMM");`?  It's nowhere in the code you've posted. Also, your demo code is completely different to your code shown here and the demo appears to work?

Comment: I post DEMO only in purpose for user to understand what I am trying to create. 
`userDetailsMM` I didn't post my View. Sorry, I will update my question

Comment: I mean, where is the attribute `userDetailsMM` on the row `tr.table-info`?  It doesn't appear to be in your code, which is probably why it's undefined.

Comment: Look at Index.cshtml. In the beggining of my code

Comment: I have and the text `userDetailsMM` doesn't appear in your code until the jquery section

Comment: @haldo I update my code right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass `"data": "id"` to controller when click table tr,you can use this:

```
$('#tblData').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            var Table = $('#tblData').DataTable(); 
            var id = Table.row(this).data().id;
           $.get("/Manager/Ticket/UserDetails?id=" + id, function (result, status) {
               $("#container").append(result);
               $("#userDetails").modal({ show: true })
           })
        });
```

**Update:**

If you want to use partial view with data TicketVM data in Index.cshtml.Here is a demo:

Models:

```
    public class TicketVM {
        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }
    public class ApplicationUser
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Client { get; set; }
    }
```

Index.cshtml(I replace `<partial name="UserDetails" />` with `<div id="modal"></div>`):

```
<br />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <h2 class="text-primary">Lista tiketa</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 text-right">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-action="Upsert"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> &nbsp; Novi tiket</a>
    </div>
</div>

<br />

<div class="p-4 border rounded">
    <table id="tblData" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr class="table-info">
                <th>Opis</th>
                <th>Datum i vrijeme slanja</th>
                <th>Vrsta Tiketa</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Datum i vrijeme zavrsetka</th>
                <th>Korisnik</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>


<div id="modal"></div>
```

UserDetails.cshtml(I change `Ticket.ApplicationUser.xxx` to `ApplicationUser.xxx`,since my Ticket model structure.IF yours structure is different from mine,you don't need to change them):

```
@model VmSTicketing.Models.ViewModels.TicketVM
<div class="modal fade" id="userDetails">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Podaci o Useru</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row dataTable">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label">Ime i Prezime</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="ApplicationUser.Name" disabled id="ImePrezime" name="ImePrezime">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br>

                <div class="row dataTable">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label">Email Adresa</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="ApplicationUser.Email" disabled id="Email" name="Email">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br>

                <div class="row dataTable">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label">Broj Telefona</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" asp-for="ApplicationUser.PhoneNumber" class="form-control" disabled id="BrTel" name="BrTel">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />

                <div class="row dataTable">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <label class="control-label">Klijent</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <input type="text" asp-for="ApplicationUser.Client" class="form-control" disabled id="klijent" name="klijent">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

GetAll(Use fake data to test,and pass prtial view to js,js will add it to `<div id="modal"></div>`):

```
 [HttpGet]
            public IActionResult UserDetails(int? Id)
            {
                TicketVM t = new TicketVM
                {
                    ApplicationUser = new ApplicationUser { Client = "client", Email = "email", Name = "name", PhoneNumber = "phone" }
            };
                
                
    
                return PartialView("UserDetails",t);
            }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: I have problem here, since my popup show but without data. SInce I checked console.log(data) it is successfully retrive data but popup modal doesn't show anything

Comment: You can refer to my updated answer.I don't understand why you use `$("#container").append(result);`I return a partial view with data to js in `GetAll`.And in js,put it into a div.

Comment: Let me test it and I will come back :) Thank you :)

Comment: Doesn't work for me ! Unfortunettly I change my mind and I put Modal to be loaded in `<a href>` link not in `<tr>`. So in Index Page in `Korisnik` I put link and when User click in Name it should be popup Modal